# Re-using Matplotlib locator to set nice axis tick locations and labels for pre-transformed data

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

Consider the following scenario:

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
assert mpl.__version__ >= '3.6'

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng(1886574108)
y = rng.exponential(size=1_000)
ytrans = np.asinh(y)

plt.hist(ytrans)
plt.show()
```

The X axis is very hard to interpret here, because it was computed on a transformed scale.

I was hoping to be able to use the built-in `matplotlib.ticker.AsinhLocator` to generate nice X ticks, but I couldn't figure it out. Here's one attempt that I tried, based on the [source code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.7.2/lib/matplotlib/scale.py#L493-L574):

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
assert mpl.__version__ >= '3.6'

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng(1886574108)
y = rng.exponential(size=1_000)
ytrans = np.arcsinh(y)

plt.hist(ytrans)

ax = plt.gca()
major_locator = mpl.ticker.AsinhLocator(1.0)
ax.xaxis.set(
    major_locator=major_locator,
    minor_locator=mpl.ticker.AsinhLocator(1.0, subs=(2, 5)),
    major_formatter=mpl.ticker.LogFormatterSciNotation(10),
    minor_formatter=mpl.ticker.NullFormatter(),
)

plt.show()
```

The scaling seems correct, however the actual choice of tick positions is bad, which is what I'm trying to use `AsinhLocator` for in the first place.

Is there a way to summon better default tick locations for pre-transformed data?

[image: Plot with non-interpretable X axis tick labels.]